# Using for loops for dispaying values in django template

Tags: python, html, mysql, django, django-templates

If I use "for loop", all data from Db are presented vertical. I wrote an example without HTML, for transparency. And second code "my.html" is with HTML code. I want to be divisions(or table) showed horizontally. If I run my.html I got two divisions displayed vertically, how can I position them horizontally? I want to display two divisions(or tables) next to each other horizontally and values like post.prop_one must be vertically displayed in division or table.

```
{% for post in posts %}
    {{post.option_one}}
    {{post.option_two}}
{% endfor %}
```

my.html

```
<!-- myprices --> 
        <div id="pricing" class="container-fluid">   
    <div class="text-center">
                <h2>Pricing</h2>
                  <h4>blabla</h4>   
</div> {% for post in posts %}
                <div class="row slideanim-'inline'">
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">

                  <div class="panel panel-default text-center">
                    <div class="panel-heading">

                  <h1><a href="">{{ post.offer_option}}</a></h1>
                    </div>
                      <div class="panel-body">
                          <p><strong>20</strong> {{post.prop_one}}</p>
                          <p><strong>20</strong>{{post.prop_two}} </p>
                          <p><strong>20</strong>{{post.prop_three}}</p>
                      </div>
                       <div class="panel-footer">
                        <h3>{{ post.price}}</h3>
                        <h4>{{ post.period}}</h4>
                       </div>
                      <button class="btn btn-lg">Sign Up</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                  {% endfor %}
```

Comment: put two tables in other table. Or use `bootstrap` classes like `"col-sm-4 col-xs-12"`

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Do you want to display items within a table horizontally (i.e. in a single table row), or do you want to display two entire tables next to each other horizontally?

Comment: Also, your example code does not use tables at all, so your question is even more unclear.

Comment: I edited my post. 
-furas: as i mantioned in post. I already use col-sm-4 and col-xs-12.
@John Gordon i want two divisons or tables dispayed next to each other horizontaly.Values like post.prop_one must be vertiacly dispayed in division or table.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you loop whole content..all you want to loop is `col-sm-4 col-xs-12`.
Your "for loop" and endingtag are wrong placed in your html.
Here is an example

```
       <!-- Container (Pricing Section) -->
<div id="pricing" class="container-fluid">
  <div class="text-center">
    <h2>Pricing</h2>
      <h4>blabla</h4>
  </div>

    <div class="row slideanim-'inline'">
        {% for post in posts %}
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">


      <div class="panel panel-default text-center">
        <div class="panel-heading">

      <h1><a href="">{{ post.offer_option}}</a></h1>
        </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
              <p><strong>20</strong> {{post.prop_one}}</p>
              <p><strong>20</strong>{{post.prop_two}} </p>
              <p><strong>20</strong>{{post.prop_three}}</p>
          </div>
           <div class="panel-footer">
            <h3>{{ post.price}}</h3>
            <h4>{{ post.period}}</h4>
           </div>
          <button class="btn btn-lg">Sign Up</button>
        </div>

      </div>{% endfor %}
    </div>
```